# C++ STL map: insert is storing null pointers

Tags: c++, stl

I have a simple class

```
    class symbol_entry
{
private:
    static unsigned long uid;

public:
    std::string name;
    std::string filename;
    unsigned int line_number;
    unsigned int column_number;
    symbol_entry* parent_symbol;
    std::map<const char*,symbol_entry*> child_symbols;
    unsigned long type_flags;

public:
    symbol_entry();
    symbol_entry(const char* name,
                 const char* filename,
                 int line_number,
                 int column_number,
                 symbol_entry* parent_symbol,
                 unsigned long type_flags);
    ~symbol_entry();

    symbol_entry* get_child(const char* name);
    bool put_child(symbol_entry* child);
};
```

here is the implementation of symbol_entry::put_child;

```
bool symbol_entry::put_child(symbol_entry* child)
{   
    if(child_symbols[child->name.c_str()])
        return false;
    child_symbols.insert(std::make_pair(child->name.c_str(),child));
    return true;
}
```

whenever i perform a test like this;

```
symbol_entry* tsym=new symbol_entry("test","$",0,0,0,0);
symbol_entry* tcsym=new symbol_entry("test_child","$",0,0,0,0);
tsym->put_child(tcsym);
std::cout<<tsym->child_symbols.begin()->first<<" => "<<tsym->child_symbols.begin()->second<<std::endl;
```

child_symbols.begin()->second is storing a null pointer. I cannot work this out and have tried many variations including const and references with to avail.

Comment: You will have to post the code of `put_child`.

Comment: Note that without a Compare object passed to your `map` (see an example at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html ) your `const char *` keys are going to be compared as pointers, not as strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`child_symbols[child->name.c_str()]` will always create and return a new map entry (a NULL one), and then `child_symbols.insert(...)` doesn't do anything (so the value in the map stays NULL). The correct way to check whether the key is already in the map is to use `find`:

```
if (child_symbols.find(...) != child_symbols.end()) // already exists
```

Comment: @jmgun87 Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you!

Comment: This isn't true. It *will* always create a NULL entry- which will be converted to `false` in the if statement and *not* return.

Comment: @DeadMG: Oh, right. But it doesn't change much, because `map::insert` will be no-op (the function reaches `return true`, but the value stays NULL).

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing pointers by value. You need to compare *what they point to*. Example:

```
std::string s1 = "Hello World!";
std::string s2 = s1;
s1.c_str() != s2.c_str()
```

This is why the use of C-strings is definitely not considered appropriate in a C++ program- `std::string` compares by value.

Comment: I agree, hence my comment on the question, but I don't see how it would prevent his example from working.

Answer (score 1):

`child_symbols[child->name.c_str()]` doesn't do what you think it does: this inserts a default object, which in your case is a `symbol_entry` pointer, every time. I could be wrong, but I think that

```
if(child_symbols[child->name.c_str()])
```

will always evaluate to `true` because `std::map` will insert an entry for you.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
child_symbols.insert(std::make_pair(child->name.c_str(),child));
```

Is not OK: you are storing the result of c_str() which is not a durable value.  It gives you a pointer to a C string which is valid right after you call it, but it's not valid for storing and reading later.  You should make your map use std::string as its key type.

Answer (score 0):

The insert will do nothing if an element already exists in the map. Your check `child_symbols[child->name.c_str()]` will create the element in its default state, so the that is what happens.

You could use `find` instead to do the check, but `insert` already has this built-in:

```
bool symbol_entry::put_child(symbol_entry* child)
{
    return child_symbols.insert(std::make_pair(child->name,child)).second;
}
```

**Edit:** Also, what DeadMG said - use `std::string` instead of `const char*` to fix that